# Flutter load image to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dart, flutter

I want to upload an image to a S3 bucket using a AWS presigned key. This curl command works:

curl -X PUT --upload-file file.txt "Signed Key (URL)"

How do I get this accomplished with dart / flutter?

Comment: Have you tried using dart `http` to make the same request you do in curl?

Comment: I have - using this code:
var request1 = http.MultipartRequest('PUT', Uri.parse(url))
        ..files.add(
          new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            'image',
            bytes,
            filename: fileName,
          ),
        );
This does not work.

Comment: are you getting some error?

Answer (score 6):

If you use Multipart Form post, the http-boundary part of the HTTP Request is stored in the first bytes of the file in S3. Don't.

This function works:

```dart
  Future<void> uploadImage(File imageFile, String url, String imagetype) async {
    final length = await imageFile.length();
    final path = imageFile.path;
    print('Uploading image length: $length path:$path to url:$url');
    try {
      var response = await http.put(url, body: imageFile.readAsBytesSync(), headers: {"Content-Type": "image/" + imagetype});
      print("Uploading image status code: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Uploading image result: ${response.body}");
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error uploading:' + error.toString());
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain the "url" what it is how can I generate this by my self